# position: fixed not working with owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css, position, fixed, owl-carousel

[page with issue is here](http://eplustv6.com/schedule/index.php)

What I'm trying to do is fix each of the column (divs) day/date headers when they scroll out of view (make them sticky) so people know what day they're looking at.  Rather than fiddle with the 'header' itself, I just set up a 2nd hidden span with fixed pos (currently visible, in red) that i'm going to show when you scroll down a bit.

They seem to load fixed properly for a flash and then take on absolute pos behavior once the carousel function loads, but i can't figure out why.

Anyone have a guess on how to fix this or do it differently?  Only requirement is to stay away from tables with this so we can make it responsive down to phone fairly easily.

I look forward to any suggestions, thanks!

Rich

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your placement:

Changed your span to div and move it to the spot shown.

and give them the css shown. The beautification part is up to you. This may not be the most aesthetic way to present this, but it does answers your question to make it fixed.

```
  <div class="day-title-fixed">Wed, Mar 12</div><!--Move it here -->
    <div id="schedule-wrap"> ....</div>



#main > div.day-title-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 510px;
    width: 126px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is ,Once a div goes fixed its width goes free and become 100%.
so the owl carousal cannot hide the coming slides properly.
To solve this ,We need to find the width of its wrapper div and give the same width to the fixed div.
we can do this by using javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divAWidth = $('#carousal-wrapper-outer').css('width');
            $('#carousal-wrapper-inner').css('width', divAWidth);    
    </script>


            <div id="carousal-wrapper-outer" style="overflow: hidden;" class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="carousal-wrapper-inner" style="position:fixed;top:30%" >
                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/dig-tab-img-1.png" alt="" /></div>
                          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/digital-1.png" alt="" /></div>
                          <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/digital-2.png" alt="" /></div>
                   </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
```